# What is wrong with my javascript code or is it opencv.js?

Tags: javascript, opencv, crash, google-chrome-devtools, imagecreatefromjpg

Chrome browser crashes after some time when I use opencv.js to receiving mjpg stream from HTML image tag.

I am wondering if it is a memory leak that I am causing.  I have monitored the Windows Task manager (memory) and the Chrome process memory crawls up.

If I comment out specific code line, there's no increase in memory (but then it doesn't do what I want).  Don't know how else to structure the code.

The HTML: (you would have to get your own opencv.js ..):

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Images</div>
    <img id="image0" alt="No Image 0"/>
    <img id="image1" alt="No Image 1"/>
    <div>Output</div>
    <canvas id="output0" width="640" height="360"></canvas>
    <canvas id="output1" width="640" height="360"></canvas>
</body>
<script src="opencv.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

And the index.js:

```js
'use strict';
const url0="http://10.0.0.58:8080/?action=stream";
const url1="http://10.0.0.58:8081/?action=stream";

image0.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
image1.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";

let image0Loaded = false;
let image1Loaded = false;

const showImage0 = () => {
            //orig had the 'cv' lines inside the setTimeout
            // then realized it's the same thing.
            // if i comment out the 'cv' code of course
            // there's no increment in memory usage. 
            let mat = cv.imread(image0);
            cv.imshow('output0',mat);
            setTimeout(()=>{
                showImage0();
            }, 50);
}
const showImage1 = () => {
            let mat = cv.imread(image1);
            cv.imshow('output1',mat);
            setTimeout(()=>{
                showImage1();
            }, 50);
}


function openCvReady() {
    cv['onRuntimeInitialized']=()=>{
        image0.onload = () => { showImage0(); }
        image1.onload = () => { showImage1(); }
        image0.src = url0;
        image1.src = url1;
    };
}

openCvReady();
```

I previously had the

Comment: the above code is served from a Raspberry Pi, browser is Windows client.  The Pi also is running 2 mjpg-streamer processes to live-feed two USB cameras.   opencv.js is 4.1.1.

Comment: nothing to do with your issue, but, are you relying on the fact that an elements id (in your case, image0 and image1) is available as a global variable of the same name? I wouldn't do that, just because it makes your code a little less obvious :p

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I think I found my answer.   Going to let it run a long time but the memory isn't crawling up anymore it's stablized.   I needed the following:

```
                mat.delete();
```